# Are the CPU cycles used up in doing a context switch accounted for in the process context?

Tags: context-switch

If a process causes a lot of context switches, will the CPU cycles used in the context switch be shown in the process CPU utilization?
In other words, if I run a process that essentially repeatedly executes a system call, then should the output of [top](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top) show an increase in CPU utilization for the process because of the increase in context switching from user to kernel space and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it should.

Look at the man pages for [`top`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) and [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) in linux and possibly other *nix systems.

Comment: man pages don't comment on this.That is why I am asking this question